# Pointcut not working with Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, logging, aop, spring-aop

In order to implement Logging using Spring AOP I followed these simple steps. But it seems like its not working. Any help would be useful

1) Created **MyLoggingAspect** class

```
    import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;

public class MyLoggingAspect
{

    public MyLoggingAspect() {
        super();
        System.out.println("Instantiated MyLoggingAspect");     
    }

    public Object log(ProceedingJoinPoint call) throws Throwable
    {
        System.out.println("from logging aspect: entering method [" + call.toShortString()
                            +"] with param:"+call.getArgs()[0] );

        Object point =  call.proceed();

        System.out.println("from logging aspect: exiting method [" + call.toShortString()   
                            + "with return as:" +point);        

        return point;
    }
```

}

2) Created a class (**TixServiceImpl**) where I want logging

```
public class TixServiceImpl implements TixService{

    @Override
    public void calculateSomething() {
        String s = "did some calculation..";
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    @Override
    public String getTixName() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

3) Created a **spring-aspectj.xml** file

```
<beans...    
    <bean id="LoggingAspect"  class = "MyLoggingAspect"/>
    <aop:config>
          <aop:aspect ref="LoggingAspect">
             <aop:pointcut id="myCutLogging"
                    expression="execution(* TixService*.*(..))"/>
             <aop:around pointcut-ref="myCutLogging" method="log"/>
          </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>    
</beans>
```

4) Created a simple test client (**TixClient**)

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext;

public class TixClient {

    public static void main(String[] a){

        ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("conf/spring-aspectj.xml");

        TixService tix = new TixServiceImpl();
        tix.calculateSomething();
        String s = tix.getTixName();

        System.out.println("End of the the client invocation!!"); 
    }   
}
```

5) It gives me the following **Output**

```
...
Instantiated MyLoggingAspect
did some calculation..
End of the the client invocation!!
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm just inspecting your code, but I have a hunch the problem is that you're not getting your `TixServiceImpl` instance from Spring, but rather you're manually instantiating it yourself in your `TixClient`.  I'm thinking your `TixService` needs to be a Spring bean, gotten from the Spring ApplicationContext, so that Spring has a chance to set up the aspects on the returned instance.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it worked. It would be good if this was mentioned in the samples/examples/tutorials available online.

Answer (score 2):

Scott Bale is right: Let spring instatiate the TixServiceImpl for you. Also in cases like this, enabling Springs logging might help because it tells you how many targets for a aspect/avice were found.

Comment: How do you turn on spring logging?

Comment: The spring documentation features various ways to enable logging: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#d0e743